# QMarginsF() not setting margins in QWebEnginePage::printToPdf

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to know if there's anyone who can help me set some margins into qt QWebEnginePage::printToPdf pdf.

I'm loading an html from some url and rendering it with QWebEnginePage and then using [printToPdf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#printToPdf) method to create the pdf file from html content.

But i'm not being able to set document margins (i've managed to set those margins with css, but i'd like to set it with the propert Qt class (QMarginsF)).

The code:

```
// NEW QT WEBENGINE PAGE
QWebEnginePage page;

// MARGINS
QMarginsF margins(75,75,75,75);

// CONNECT
QObject::connect( &page, &QWebEnginePage::loadFinished, [&page, output, &margins]()
{
    // qDebug(QString("Margins: %1").arg(margins.top()).toStdString().c_str());

    // PRINT TO PDF
    page.printToPdf( [output](const QByteArray &data)
    // LAMBDA (print2pdf first param)
    {
        QFile file(output);

        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            return;
        }

        file.write( data );

        system( (" xdg-open " + output).toStdString().c_str() );

        QApplication::exit(0);
    },
    // PAGE LAYOUT (print2pdf second param)
    QPageLayout( QPageSize( QPageSize::A4 ), QPageLayout::Portrait, margins));

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Precisely what version of Qt5 are you using?